How to make a fluid with Geometry Nodes particles?
EDIT:
Hi friends.
How can I make a fluid with Geometry Nodes? Is there a tutorial available?
I found this free resource/blender file of particle fluids with Geometry Nodes, and I want to learn how to do it:
https://file.io/asdHtAjLsgC5
https://easyupload.io/7l92iu
Thanks in advance.



Please just focus on the problem you're having: how to make your liquid thinner. You can post screenshots of what it currently looks like and what the desired result is. That it happens to be something your trying to duplicate doesn't really matter for the question. (And I have a feeling it's a simple fix with a certain setting (resolution?)). Did you also check to see if it's allowed to reupload the free file?

What is the question? Do you try to understand the file? Or do you want just to replicate a similar result? The "fake liquid" in the provided blend file is made with the help of a particle system and a Geometry Nodes (GN) modifier that does a remesh/merge of the particle instances. Another GN modifier adds some fake surface tension. It projects the vertices that are close to the surface on the surface (at least it should do this but I think there is a bug). A few more modifiers are used to smooth the liquid. Long story short, there are no metaballs like you have.

Thank you very much friends for your answers. I have already edited the thread and added screenshots. Yes, I wanted to know how it works so I can replicate it myself. Thanks for the explanation, I thought you needed metaballs. I didn't even know Geometry Nodes existed, I'm a noob and nodes are quite complicated for me. I'm going to try to find a tutorial on how to use Geometry Nodes to create a water flow. If I can't do it in a few days, I'll consider this thread solved, since I won't have the level to do that for now. Thanks again!

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

You can use a Particle System, an low-poly sphere with a Particle Instance modifier to create a mesh of fluid, and then add a few Geometry Nodes to make it look more liquid.

Step 1: create a plane (=emitter), and set up the Particle System with fluid physics. You can uncheck [X] Show Emitter if you don't wont to render the plane.

Step 2: add a collision object with a Collision modifier, e.g. floor and walls. Make sure the normals are correct. Customize the settings for Particles as desired.

Step 3: create a low-poly icosphere with a Particle Instance modifier to have geometry for the particles.

Step 4: create a Geometry Nodes modifer with a few nodes like Mesh to Volume and Volume to Mesh to merge an remesh the particle mesh. It uses the geometry of the ico-sphere (step 3).

Step 5: add a few more modifiers:

a Smooth modifier to smooth the mesh.
a Displacement modifier and a texture to add very subtle surface irregularities. I think you only need this if you have the Smooth modifier set very aggressively or depending on how strong the viscosity of the liquid should be.
another Geometry nodes modifier ("GN shrink fluid above the surface") which moves all vertices located below the surface to the surface of the floor and walls.
finally, the last Geometry nodes modifier ("GN project normal to nearby surface") that simulates surface tension by projecting vertices that are close to the surface onto the surface. The modifier is shown in the screenshot and looks very similar to the "GN shrink fluid above the surface" modifier.
last but not least, another Smooth modifier to smooth everything.


You can turn off the modifiers in the viewport to see the effect:

The thickness of the beam can be influenced with the Threshold setting of the Volumne to Mesh node of the first GN modifier, but I honestly don't know why the beam is a little too thick at the beginning.
I recommend experimenting with the setting Particle System > Physics > Advanced > Rest Density, which determines how closely the particles stick together. Also, try a Subdivision Surface modifier on the ico-sphere.
 (Blender 3.6)

Omg, that was really a lot of work. I don't know if you'll read this, but I really appreciate it!!! I downloaded the .blend file and I'm studying your guide to understand everything step by step and be able to do it myself. Again, thanks a lot friend!
